# JavaScript navigation menu multiple onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I am getting in touch with javascript and just having problem with multiple onClick attribute. I already have some code but it seems to be easier and neater way to solve an issue.

I would like to have navigation menu which hyperlink background gets a color onClick and blog div changes its content. Also if you click on another hyperlink it changes the background color and other hyperlink is reset to its original background color

here's my code so far. Seems to be working but not sure if this is a way

--
HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navigation_bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="red" id="1"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv1(this)">NavMenu1</a></li>
                <li class="red" id="2"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv2(this)">NavMenu2</a></li>
                <li class="red" id="3"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv3(this)">NavMenu3</a></li>
                <li class="red" id="4"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv4(this)">NavMenu4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="blog">
        <div id="category_1" style="display: none">
            <img src="#" alt="xx" />
            <article>
                <p>Content of first navigation bar</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div id="category_2" style="display: none;">
            <article>
                <p>Content of second navigation button</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

javascript

```
function showDiv1(obj) {
    var elchosen = document.getElementById('category_1');
    elchosen.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    var spanID = obj.parentNode.id;
    var newNode = document.getElementById(spanID);

    var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("rood");
    for (var i = menus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(menus[i].id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

    }

    newNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function showDiv2(obj) {

    var elchosen = document.getElementById('category_1');
    elchosen.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');

    var elchosen = document.getElementById('category_2');
    elchosen.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    var spanID = obj.parentNode.id;
    var newNode = document.getElementById(spanID);

    var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
    for (var i = menus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(menus[i].id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

    }

    newNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Just wondering if there is simple way to go by using something like category_n and showDiv(n) etc. just not to write same code for each operation as I have above.

I really appreciate any advice as am just at the beginning of my journey to get deep understanding of javascript.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has a jQuery tag I'll answer using that.  Replace your javascript with something like

```
//Use a delegated event.  Every click on an "a" element within the ##navigation_bar will trigger this
$('#navigation_bar').on('click', 'a', function(){
   // Get li containing the link clicked
   var li = $(this).closest('li');

   // Hide all blog.  Better to use a category on the div like $('.category', '#blog');
   $('#blog > div').hide();
   // Show the one we want to show based on the id of li
   $('#category_' + li.attr('id')).show();

   // Instead of setting colours we change classes.  Remove the red class from all menu items
   $('li', '#navigation_bar').removeClass('red');
   // Add the red class to the active menu item
   li.addClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the whole issue with using anchors and CSS using :target. If you changed your HTML to

```
<li class="red" id="1"><a href="#category_1">NavMenu1</a></li>
<li class="red" id="2"><a href="#category_2">NavMenu2</a></li>
<li class="red" id="3"><a href="#category_3">NavMenu3</a></li>
<li class="red" id="4"><a href="#category_4">NavMenu4</a></li>
```

and then added the following CSS

```
#blog>div {
 display:none;
}

#blog>div:target {
 display:block;
}
```

It would take care of the showing and hiding the div articles. You would not even need Javascript except to take care of the menu items. You could have a simple jQuery listeners to change the navigation colors like the following

```
$('nav li a').click(function(){
   $('nav li').removeClass('red');
   $(this).parent().addClass('red');

   //Use this line to prevent scrolling to the blog and instead scroll to the top of the page
   window.setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Nice!  It does mean you will also jump to the start of the blog in question of course (which could be a Good Thing or not depending on the design)

Comment: Yes that is very true. I hadn't considered that but if its desired then great!

Comment: I just added a statement that can fix the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*save this file name as script.js*/


function ChangePagetoHome()
{

    $("#A").show();
    $("#B").hide();
    $("#C").hide();

}


function ChangePagetoContact()
{
    $("#A").hide();
    $("#B").show();
    $("#C").hide();

}


function ChangePagetoProfile()
{
    $("#A").hide();
    $("#B").hide();
    $("#C").show();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="A">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" onclick="ChangePagetoHome();">Home</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="ChangePagetoContact();">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="ChangePagetoProfile();">My profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Hi I Am Home</p>
</div>

<div id="B" style="display: none;">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a onclick="ChangePagetoHome();">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" onclick="ChangePagetoContact();">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="ChangePagetoProfile();">My profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Hi I Am Contact</p>
</div>

<div id="C" style="display: none;">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a  onclick="ChangePagetoHome();">Home</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="ChangePagetoContact();">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" onclick="ChangePagetoProfile();">My profile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Hi I Am Profile</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**This is a very simple example to make a JavaScript navigation Menu Don't forget to insert jQuery in this code and there is no requirement of href="#"**